# Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I am writing a small test for checking if some code does write into my mongo database. I am receiving the following error message from Jest, the code does indeed work.

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

For my test I am only calling the function and expecting a object property which specifies if the operation was succesfull

```js
const {clearDataBase, loadData} = require('../src/utils/dataloader')

beforeEach(clearDataBase)
test('Should write all data into database', () => {   
    jest.setTimeout(30000);
    const result = loadData() 
    expect(result.status).toBe(201)
})
```

The original function parses a JSON file and saves certain pars into the database :

```js
const loadData = () => {
    try{
        request(url, async (err, res, body) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(body)
            // ... Loads a lot of data, removed for this post only!
        })
        return { error: undefined, status: 201 }
    } catch(e){
        return { error: e, status: undefined }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Promises to make sure that `expect()` is called only after `loadData` function is executed.
[Jest Async doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous)

Modified your code below to use promises

```
const {clearDataBase, loadData} = require('../src/utils/dataloader')

beforeEach(clearDataBase)
test('Should write all data into database', () => {   
    jest.setTimeout(30000);
    loadData().then(result => expect(result.status).toBe(201));
})


const loadData = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return request(url, async (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) return reject({error: err})
    const data = JSON.parse(body)
    // ... Loads alot of data, removed for this post only!
    return resolve({ error: undefined, status: 201 })
  })
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't this promise be turned into an actual promise?  I got the followin error:
TypeError: loadData(...).then is not a function

Comment: I was assuming your `request(url, ...)` is returning a promise? Where are you getting this function from?

Comment: I am using the Request package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: Looks like you it doesn't support promises, you can use request-promise library as suggested in their docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait
Or you can modify loadData to use callbacks instead of then

Comment: I modified my code to return promises but I was still getting the same error, should I just switch to it?

Comment: I wrapped my code to return a promise. It should work now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206764/discussion-between-gaurav-and-jeremy).